# Wireguard Connection Dies on Ubuntu Peer

Tags: ssh, wireguard

I live in a building where the network is behind a NAT. I have a Linux desktop PC and a laptop. In order to access my desktop via ssh, I have a Wireguard VPN running on my desktop, laptop and a VPS. The issue is that connection between my desktop and the VPS dies.

Here is the VPS config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.9.0.1/24
SaveConfig = false
#PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -$
#PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING$
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = **SERVER PRIVATE KEY**

[Peer]
PublicKey = **LINUX DESKTOP PUBLIC KEY**
AllowedIPs = 10.9.0.2/32
PersistentKeepalive = 5

[Peer]
PublicKey = **LAPTOP PUBLIC KEY**
AllowedIPs = 10.9.0.3/32
PersistentKeepalive = 20
```

Here is the Linux desktop's config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = **LINUX DESKTOP PRIVATE KEY**
Address = 10.9.0.2/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = **SERVER PUBLIC KEY**
Endpoint = *MY ENDPOING IP*
AllowedIPs = 10.9.0.1/32, 10.9.0.3/32
```

From the above config, you can see that I don't allow `0.0.0.0\0` from any client. **I only want to tunnel SSH traffic through the VPS. If I only allow traffic from SSH the connection between my laptop and Linux desktop dies in a minute or two. To revive the connection, I have to ping the VPS from the desktop.**

This problem does not happen if I route all traffic through the VPS. However, I don't want to do that (Google Captcha is annoying and also I don't have the bandwidth on the VPS).

Any thoughts on how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `PersistentKeepalive` settings from your VPS WireGuard config to your Desktop and Laptop WireGuard configs. Usually you want `PersistentKeepalive` on the side of the connection that's behind NAT, as it will automatically send keepalive packets to "open a hole" in the NAT, allowing the non-NAT side to initiate new connections (or re-establish lapsed connections) through the WireGuard tunnel. When you ping the VPS from your Desktop, you're doing the same thing, manually.

Comment: That was it. Thank you.